# Cakephp view not working

Tags: cakephp, view, controller

When I want to see for example `localhost/pages/index`, the localhost page is shown. The controller is working (the debug shows proper value defined in the controller). Also the title of the `localhost/pages/index` is set properly ("Posts"). Can somebody help me?

The page is in `/app/View/webroot`

Also, the view is working, when `die()` inserted in the end of `index.ctp` it is shown properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost/pages/index` refers to a file called `index.ctp` in `app/View/pages`

`app/View/webroot` is for your assets - images, css, js and so on.